# How to automate a complex series of git history rewrites?

Tags: git, git-rebase

## Situation

Let's say I wanted to always rebase before merging, but noticed very late that I forgot to do so and now commit E and C have the same parent:

```
I (branch-1)
|\
| H (branch-2)
| |\
| | G
| |/
| F
| |\
| | E
| D |
| |\ \
| | |/
| |/|
| | C
| |/
B |
 \|
  A
```

I would like to "untangle" the history as such:

```
I (branch-1)
|\
| H (branch-2)
| |\
| | G
| |/
| F
| |\
| | E
| |/
| D
| |\
| | C
| |/
B |
 \|
  A
```

The only way I see is quite cumbersome and would involve a lot of successive history changing commands like `git rebase --onto ...` and `git reset --hard ...` where most of the supplied commit hashes (the `...`) would be known only half way through the process.

## Question

Is there a more automated way to untangle the graph? Can we make a script for such a history rewrite, in which we use just the information from the initial state?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've only got one set of content changes to make, that's a one-commit rebase:

```
git rebase --onto D E
```

but everything else will have identical content in the new history, so after the easy rebase do:

```
git replace E @
git filter-branch -- --all
```

with whatever options you want for moving existing tags and such.  `F`, `G`, `H` and `I` will be rewritten with new ancestry but identical content, and of course `E` will have new ancestry and the merged-from-`D` content.

Answer (score -1):

Try the [`-r|--rebase-merges`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--r) option of `git rebase` :

```
git rebase -r -i A
```

The sequencer will have more options, and allow you to describe a script which replays or creates merges.

You may either carefully rewrite that sequencer script,
or :

- add a `break` instruction right after merging `E` and `D` to `F`,
- manually fix `E` and `F` from the terminal,
- proceed with the rebase using `git rebase --continue`.

---

If `E` is a sequence of commits rather than a single commit, you may want to first create `E'` (which would be `git rebase --onto D A E`) before running that sequence, because you won't be able to "rebase while interrupting a rebase" at step 2.

Step 2 would become : replace `F` with `git merge -C F E'`.